# I have a Problem with cron-job.org php file

Tags: php

I have a php file that check data from a txt file and then if it finds a specific data in the txt file it sends message to telegram using telegram api

I need to run this php file every day , but my free host doesn't support Cron jobs , so I tried to use cron-job.org but each time I test to Cron job I revive this response and the file not executed :

> Server: nginx Date: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 21:09:29 GMT Content-Type:
> text/html Content-Length: 848 Connection: keep-alive Vary:
> Accept-Encoding Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT Cache-Control:
> no-cache
>
> function toNumbers(d) { var e = []; d.replace(/(..)/g, function (d) { e.push(parseInt(d, 16)) }); return e } function toHex()
> { for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length &&
> arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "",
> f = 0; f  d[f] ? "0" : "") +
> d[f].toString(16); return e.toLowerCase() } var a =
> toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"), b =
> toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"), c =
> toNumbers("d61ae965428c82887a530079c50d1343"); document.cookie =
> "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu,
> 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href = "myUrl";
>     This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with
>         Javascript support

Comment: Seems like you sent the request to some front-end file which requires JavaScript. Surely you should be targeting a PHP file which runs PHP code, without any user-interface content? But we don't have a [mre] of the issue, so we can only guess based on the response. See also [ask] - if we can't see your code or your cron config then we are very limited in what answers we can give.

Comment: Sounds like this is some "bot protection" implemented either directly by your hoster, or using some service like Cloudflare. You'll have to contact their support to ask if this can be disabled / circumvented somehow - but I would not get my hopes up, if I were you.